# How to import excel file with over 100k rows into MySQL database using java

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am getting error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied
>   data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part
>   of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a
>   different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.(POIFSFileSystem.java:86)
>     at importdata.Snomed10.main(Snomed10.java:28)

My code:

```
package importdata;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
public class Snomed10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/snomedinfo","root","root");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement pstm = null ;
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D://icd10 to snomed.xlsx");
           POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
            //HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
            //HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
           XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
           XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            Row row;
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.US);
            for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
                row = sheet.getRow(i);



                String id = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0));
                int effectiveTime = (int) row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
                int active = (int) row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
                String moduleId = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(3));
                String refSetId = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(4));
                String referencedComponentId = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(5));
                String sctName = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(6));
                int mapGroup = (int) row.getCell(7).getNumericCellValue();
                int mapPriority = (int) row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue();
                String mapRule = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(9));
                String mapAdvice = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(10));
                String mapTarget =formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(11));
                String icdName = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(12));
                int mmapCategoryId = (int) row.getCell(13).getNumericCellValue();
                String mapCategoryValue = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(14));

                //String sql = "INSERT INTO sno10 VALUES('"+id+"','"+effectiveTime+"','"+active+"',"
                        //+ "'"+moduleId+"','"+refSetId+"','"+referencedComponentId+"',"
                                //+ "'"+sctName +"','"+mapGroup+"','"+mapPriority+"',"
                                        //+ "'"+mapRule+"','"+mapAdvice+"','"+mapTarget+"',"
                                            //  + "'"+icdName+"','"+mmapCategoryId+"','"+mapCategoryValue+"')";
                //pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
               // pstm.execute();

                String sql = "INSERT INTO sno10 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);

                pstm.setString(1, id);
                pstm.setInt(2, effectiveTime);
                pstm.setInt(3, active);
                pstm.setString(4, moduleId);
                pstm.setString(5, refSetId);
                pstm.setString(6, referencedComponentId);
                pstm.setString(7, sctName);
                pstm.setInt(8, mapGroup);
                pstm.setInt(9, mapPriority);
                pstm.setString(10, mapRule);
                pstm.setString(11, mapAdvice);
                pstm.setString(12, mapTarget);
                pstm.setString(13, icdName);
                pstm.setInt(14, mmapCategoryId);
                pstm.setString(15,mapCategoryValue);
                pstm.execute();



                System.out.println("Import rows "+i);
            }
            con.commit();
            pstm.close();
            con.close();
            input.close();
            System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: go for Sax parser .... or divide your excel in 4 parts

Comment: Did you try doing exactly what the Error message told you to do, and switched your `HSSF` code (.xls) for `XSSF` code (.xlsx)?

Comment: @Gagravarr yes i converted before , if i convert xls file it will take only 65 k rows not more done that i need to import more than 1 lakh rows

Answer (score 1):

If we look at this snippet here:

```
 FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D://icd10 to snomed.xlsx");
 POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
 //HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
 XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
```

We see the problem. Well, two problems, but...

As [explained in the JavaDocs, POIFSFileSystem](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.html) is the low level code for reading OLE2 files such as `.xls`. It can't open OOXML files like `.xlsx`, which is exactly what the exception tells you!

Secondly, as [explained in the docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), don't use a stream if you have a file!

So, your code should instead be something like:

```
File input = new File("D://icd10 to snomed.xlsx");
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(input);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```

Comment: its taking more time to run at least 45 sec and showing this error @Gagravarr

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: @bala So increase the size of your heap space! See one of the hundreds of questions here on how to do that...

Comment: i have increased the size of 1024 m even though its showing like that , if u have similar code to upload above 1 lakh excel rows in mysql DB cloud you share it to me ,  its very helpful for me , @Gagravarr

Comment: Apache POI works just fine for me, even on large files! Did you try [following the advice in the Apache POI FAQ on memory and performance](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109)?

Comment: i saw that link , but if you share your source code means it will help full to me .@Gagravarr